# Magento Add value in custom column of sales_flat_order table

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

Hi i have made a custom column in **sales_flat_order** table named **final_shipping_amount**. When i am loading order its showing my custom column in it. I am trying to add value in my custom column but its not adding value in it here is my code.

```
$final_shipping = "1.33"
$orderIid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
$orderDataShip = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderIid);
$orderDataShip->setFinalShippingAmount($final_shipping);
$orderDataShip->save();
```

Its not saving value in it. i have also tried this way but also its not saving

```
$final_shipping = "1.33"
$orderIid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
$orderDataShip = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderIid);
$orderDataShip->setData('final_shipping_amount' , $final_shipping);
$orderDataShip->save();
```

but its not working.

Comment: Make sure you are getting `$orderIid` and it loads a valid sales order entity.

Comment: its a valid order id i have checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing the Magento cache (both the Magento cache and Storage cache)..or you can simply delete the files from `var/cache`.

Comment: yeah you are right when i delete these folders not its working